# Routes horizon and websockets

Tags: laravel, websocket, routes, laravel-middleware, horizon

I use Horizon and web sockets with Laravel. How can I allow access to the two services for administrators only?
Do I just have to create a new middleware for this?

example:

```
/*
     * Dashboard Routes Middleware
     *
     * These middleware will be assigned to every dashboard route, giving you
     * the chance to add your own middleware to this list or change any of
     * the existing middleware. Or, you can simply stick with this list.
     */
    'middleware' => [
        'web',
        Authorize::class,
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to see Horizon's dashboard, there should be a configuration already in place. Check your `config/app.php` has the following in the providers array:

> 'providers' => [ ...,
> App\Providers\HorizonServiceProvider::class
> ]

Later you could just define the gate access logic in the `app/Providers/HorizonServiceProvider.php`, probably something like:

```
protected function gate()
{
    Gate::define('viewHorizon', function ($user) {
        return $user->isAdmin();
    });
}
```

In your User model, implement the function logic `isAdmin()` for who is admin. This is one way to go.

More details in https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/horizon#dashboard-authorization

For the web socket, you can create a middleware just fine, similar to the previous example to determine who has access inside the handle function.